# Sudden error SSHing into EC2 instance

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2

I've been using an ec2 instance for a couple of weeks with no issues. Out of nowhere today the instance would no longer let me login with my private. I get

> Server refused our key
>
> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server
>   sent: publickey)

I can't figure out why this started happening out of nowhere today. I tried rebooting the instance but no luck so I imaged the instance and launched a new instance from the image with a fresh key pair. I'm getting the same error when logging into this new instance with the new private key.

I'm using a basic security group which is open

> 22 (SSH)  0.0.0.0/0
>
> 80 (HTTP) 0.0.0.0/0
>
> 443 (HTTPS)   0.0.0.0/0
>
> 8080 (HTTP*)  0.0.0.0/0

Anyone come across this before or have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Derm

Comment: How are you specifying the private key from the SSH client? Are you using an SSH agent or are you explicitly passing the private key?

Comment: Are sure about the username that you use for SSH? e.g. it is `ubuntu` for ubuntu instances and `ec2-user` for RHEL instnaces.

Comment: what is the ssh command you are trying with

Comment: I've been using putty and winscp. I generated a key using puttygen and my private key and pass that in through the apps. I built off an amazon image so ec2-user is the correct user. Again this was all working fine for 2 weeks and suddenly stopped working yesterday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of messing around I figured out the issue. In case anyone comes across a similar issue… Running a custom script I accidentally messed up the permissions on the ec2-user home directory which locked the ec2-user out of the server.

To fix it I detached the root volume from the instance (using the CLI ec2-detach-volume) and attached it to another temp instance (using the CLI ec2-attach-volume), mounting it in a temp folder and changing the permissions on the ec2-user directory to og-rwx.

I then detached the volume from the temp instance and re-attached it as root to the original instance and was able to ssh in again with my original key.